ASP.NET Core 2.2 - Swagger Serialization Upper CamelCase after Migration to System.Text.Json
I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API using Swagger.
I recently upgraded from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0 to 6.5.
Besides some minor issues I just realized that the new serialization with System.Text.Json (instead of Newtonsoft.Json) now generates the swagger.json file with property names in camel case starting with an uppercase letter, while Newtonsoft.Json generated it with lowercase camel case.
How can I configure it, so that the swagger.json looks the same as before the upgrade?
Before upgrade:
"Geschlecht": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "displayName": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "description": ""
      },

After upgrade:
"Geschlecht": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Key": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "DisplayName": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "description": ""
      },

Of course I could decorate every property in my model with the attribute [JsonPropertyName("key")], but I'd rather configure it globally.
I tried different ContractResolver with no success:
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(json => json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

It's suspicious to me, that SerializerSettings is part of the Newtonsoft namespace. I haven't found an equivalent setting for the System.Text.Json namespace.

Check out the JsonSerializerOptions - see the official MS docs on it here

JsonSerializerOptions isn't available in MvcJsonOptions in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json Version 2.2

Seems like ASP.NET Core 2.2 is just too old to have any meaningful support for System.Text.Json - sorry ....
